# confusion about synchronizing an object for a block in Java

Tags: java, object, locking, wait, synchronized

```
public class ThreadConfusion
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.print("1 ");
        synchronized (args) 
        {
            System.out.println(" 2");
            try
            {
                args.wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.out.println("exception");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("3 ");
    } //end of the main method
} // end of the class
```

output

```
1  2
```

Why does the output is 1 2 rather than 1 2 3. What happened exactly over there?

Comment: why did you called wait() ? Its waiting for you to call notify()

Comment: More importantly : who do you expect to call `args.notify()`? There are no other threads here...

Answer (score 0):

Because no one invokes `notify()`. Your main thread will wait indefinitely.

From the javadoc of `wait()`:

> Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the
>   notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object.

If you want to wait call `Thread.sleep()`;

Answer (score 0):

```
args.wait();
```

[wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29)

> Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object.

You are telling that `wait`(lock on the object) the `thread` (`main`) forever.

give

```
  try{args.wait(5000);}
```

And see that the wait finishes after 5 sec and prints `3`

or call `notify()`